# select rand() from subquery

Tags: sql, random, subquery

I have apparently simple query:

```
SELECT tag_id 
from books_tags 
WHERE tag_id IN (SELECT tag_id 
                 FROM books_tags 
                 GROUP BY tag_id 
                 ORDER BY COUNT(tag_id) DESC 
                 LIMIT 100) 
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 1
```

I wish to select one random record from query inside. It does not work, error says that LIMIT and ORDER cannot appear in subquery.

I dont wanna create temporary table, or random on servers side. Any ideas how to merge it into wone query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do the same with `INNER JOIN` / `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

```
SELECT a.tag_id 
from books_tags a
INNER JOIN  (SELECT tag_id 
                 FROM books_tags 
                 GROUP BY tag_id 
                 ORDER BY COUNT(tag_id) DESC 
                 LIMIT 100) b ON a.tag_id = b.tag_id
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 1
```